# How to find proper model formula?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have a repeated-measures 2-factor experiment with 8x4 levels of factors, in a fully crossed design. I'm trying to fit a linear mixed-effects model (lme4::lmer), but I struggle with defining a proper model formula. Also, I think my model should factor in the dependency, that the 8 levels of the first factor (render algorithms) were displayed simultaneously next to each other and were rated as in comparison between them, four times - manipulating the second factor (example the render was computed on).

Here are the data plots, grouped by examples:

[image: rating score of 8 different renders at 4 examples]

I also have the plot [grouped by renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow4T1.png), the [boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMrB0.png), and the [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7F98.png) of my data.

I think I should use the formula similar to this one:

```
score ~ render*example + (subject|example)
```

but I'm not sure if the random effects are defined properly. Maybe it should be the other way around, (example|subject)? Or two separate terms, (1|subject) + (1|example)? I was also considering the "||" operator (uncorrelated random intercept and slope) but I'm not sure if it should be used in my case.

Also, I tried comparing a few model formulae by AIC and LogLik criteria, but most of them throw a warning, which I'm not sure is something I should ignore:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

However, this only happens when I use ML method. When I use REML, the warning doesn't show in most cases.

Finally, at some point I was blindly tring different formulae, and I have found one which shows best AIC and LogLik - but it just makes no sense to me:

```
score ~ render*example + subject*example + subject*render + (1|subject)
```

So, to sum up my questions: what is the model formula derived solely from the experiment design? Can I ignore the warning I'm receiving? What to think about the formula which appears to be the best?